# How can the same move command behave differently depending on the context?

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, mv

This should be trivial really, I have a script that compile an app then bundle it into a dmg.

The steps are:

1. `make`
2. `mv app.app/ installer/artifacts/`
3. `createDMG`

The problem is this runs within a CI system and it fail because it can't find the app.app in the artifacts folder. Indeed if I look at what's inside this folder I can only see a `Content` folder which is supposed to be app.app's child folder. Now I don't think that the command to move the app.pp folder is wrong because when I run all those 3 steps it works just fine...

I'm a bit confused now, how can 2 move command can have 2 different behaviors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder installer/artifacts/ does not exist, move will rename app.app/ to installer/artifacts/

You could do the following instead:

```
make
mkdir -p installer/artifacts/
mv app.app installer/artifacts/
createDMG
```

Comment: it's a good point actually... everything should be in git but since the folder is empty it won't be created during a pull... and then when it fail and I go check it it exist since the app.app took it's place by being renamed... I will give it a go but almost sure you are right !